# Why I cannot find ldap.conf file when I want to integrate 389-ds and samba on centos 7?

Tags: ldap, samba4, 389-ds, pam-ldap

I am working on two servers, a samba server and a 389-ds server. Now I want to integrate them so that samba shares are authenticated via ldap server.
I have followed instructions on http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-samba.html and now I have gotten a problem.
As said in the PAM configuration page ( http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-pam.html ) I wanted to run the command

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --disablenis --enablecache  
--ldapserver=host.example.com --ldapbasedn=dc=example,dc=com --updateall
```

But I spotted that there is no file `ldap.conf` in `/etc` to be updated via this command. Also, the command `find / -name ldap.conf` only results in the file `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` that belongs to openldap and is not the point of my job. I also ran the command `find / -name *ldap.conf` because I had read that the `/etc/ldap.conf` is renamed to `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` on centos 6 and I thought that perhaps it is the same on centos 7. But the command results wasn't what I was searching for.
I've also installed `nss_ldap`, `nslcd`, `sssd` and `smbldap-tools` on ldap server and started their services. For more clarification, running `yum list installed | grep ldap` results in:

```
ldapjdk.noarch
nss-pam-ldapd.x86_64
openldap.x86_64
openldap-clients.x86_64
openldap-servers.x86_64
sssd-ldap.x86_64
```

But main problem still exists: the file `ldap.conf` does not exist.

Comment: Why is this a problem ? Are you saying that the authconfig command doesn't create the conf file or that you don't want to run the authconfig command because the conf file doesn't exist?

Comment: @lain In the documentation page, it is said that `authconfig` command will update `ldap.conf` file and won't create it. However, I ran the command and the file wasn't created.

Comment: Running `yum whatprovides /etc/ldap.conf` returns `No matches found` which suggests that there are no packages that contain the file. Try creating a blank file touch /etc/ldap.conf.

Answer (score 0):

The `ldap.conf` file, often used for configuring LDAP client settings, may not exist by default on CentOS 7. Instead, you should use the `ldap.conf` file provided by the OpenLDAP client package, which is used for LDAP client configuration.

Here are some steps to configure LDAP client settings for integrating 389-ds (389 Directory Server) and Samba on CentOS 7:

1. **Install OpenLDAP Client Package**:
   If you haven't already, install the OpenLDAP client package on your CentOS 7 system. You can do this with the following command:

   ```bash
   sudo yum install openldap-clients
   ```
2. **Configure LDAP Client**:
   Once the OpenLDAP client is installed, you can create and configure the `ldap.conf` file to define your LDAP client settings. You can create this file manually in the `/etc/openldap/` directory. Here's an example:

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
   ```

   Then, add your LDAP client configuration to this file. An example `ldap.conf` file might look like this:

   ```
   URI ldap://your-ldap-server.example.com
   BASE dc=example,dc=com
   BINDDN cn=ldapuser,dc=example,dc=com
   BINDPW your-ldap-password
   ```

   Adjust the settings to match your LDAP server's configuration. The `URI` should point to your LDAP server's address, and `BASE` should specify the base DN of your LDAP directory. `BINDDN` and `BINDPW` specify the LDAP user and password for authentication.
3. **Restart LDAP Service**:
   After configuring the `ldap.conf` file, you may need to restart the LDAP service to apply the changes:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart nslcd
   ```
4. **Test LDAP Integration**:
   You can test the LDAP integration by using the `ldapsearch` command to query your LDAP server:

   ```bash
   ldapsearch -x -LLL -D "cn=ldapuser,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "dc=example,dc=com"
   ```

   This command searches the LDAP directory using the specified credentials and base DN.

Please note that the LDAP server and user details in the example are placeholders, and you should replace them with your actual LDAP server configuration. Additionally, ensure that you have a functioning 389-ds server set up and properly configured to integrate with Samba.